# How to display the current state of reducer?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Trying to get my head around the ngrx/store api for angular 2. I implemented a simple counter reducer:

```
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store'

export const INCREMENT ='INCREMENT';
export const DECREMENT='DECREMENT';


export const counter = (state = 0, {type, payload}) => {
  switch(type){
    case INCREMENT:
      return state=state+1;
    case DECREMENT:
      return state=state-1;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I want to display the counter value:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'todo-app',
    providers: [],
    template: `
    <div>

    <nextStepButton (next)="prev()"></nextStepButton>

    <nextStepButton (next)="next()"></nextStepButton>

    how to display the counter:{{counter.val}}

    <log-monitor></log-monitor>

  `,
    directives: [LogMonitor, myList, step, nextStepButton, step2],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

How can I display the counter ie reducer value in the template?

githublink:https://github.com/dimitri-a/ngrx_newtoy

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/ngrx/store. You have to declare the reducer as an observable.